# how to use 'alternate' in animation CSS on slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a slide show with `CSS` and `HTML`. it's working good but I want it to work like this:

slide1 => slide2 => slide3 => slide4 => slide5 
and when it reaches the fifth slide it'll go back the to first one, like this:
slide1 <= slide2 <= slide3 <= slide4 <= slide5

and this animation just goes back and forth and it should never stop.

this my code :
http://jsfiddle.net/thFLB/

Comment: You can use this code its does the same thing but it's start from first so you just need to start from second last http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava yeah my friend I use this code but I don't know how to start from second last!!!

Comment: just add a logic the way it keep moving right to left so find when the last end just add animation from there in -ve.Hope it helps...